# Mailbox name not allowed

Tags: asp.net

I am having a problem to send out a test email using "system.net.mail". The error message " Mailbox name not allowed. The server response was: 5.3.0 Relaying denied check mail first" every time I press the submit button. Thank you in advance.

Code_behind:

```
public class MailHelper
{
    public static void SendMailMessage(string from, string to, string bcc,
        string cc, string subject, string body)
    {
        MailMessage mMailMessage = new MailMessage();
        mMailMessage.From = new MailAddress(from);
        mMailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(to));
        if ((bcc != null) && (bcc != string.Empty))
        {
            mMailMessage.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress(bcc));
        }
        if ((cc != null) && (cc != string.Empty))
        {
            mMailMessage.CC.Add(new MailAddress(cc));
        }
        mMailMessage.Subject = subject;
        mMailMessage.Body = body;
        mMailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mMailMessage.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;

        string smtpServer = "";
        //Read the Web.config to get configuration setting
        smtpServer=System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtp"];
        // Instantiate a new instance of SmtpClient
        SmtpClient mSmtpClient = new SmtpClient(smtpServer);
        // Send the mail message
        mSmtpClient.Send(mMailMessage);
    }       
}
```

Web_config:

```
<appSettings>
<add key="smtp" value="smtp.mydomain.com"/>
</appSettings>
<system.net>
<mailSettings>
<smtp from="defaultEmail@mydomain.com">
<network host="smtp.mydomain.com" port="25" userName="yourUserName" password="yourPassword"/>
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Sumbit_Click:

```
 protected void Sumbit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MailHelper.SendMailMessage("from@email.com", "to@email.com", null, null,
            "subject", "textEnquiry.Text");
    }
```

Comment: Sounds like a mail server issue, so you should investigate the configuration there. You could try a different "from" address. Also consider using String.IsNullOrEmpty(bcc) and checking to see if it's a valid email before adding. And since you have the info in the web.config you should just be able to say new SmtpClient(); and be done with it.

Comment: The mail server requires you to log on via POP before it allows you to send a message. This is a mechanism to prevent unprivileged senders to use the mail server. If the mail server is under your control you could alternatively change the relaying/authorization settings.

Comment: This is a school project to send a test email to any domain. I am using my school domain to test the email, but it seem like the server denied it. Can I used gmail and yahoo mail to test it? How do I know if the email is successful send?